# Cheap non-toxic hydrophobic (spray) coating for fabrics?

Tags: clothing, fabric

I would like to make my clothes to repel water (with hydrophobic coating?). Any suggestion of not-so-expensive method to achieve this?

Comment: Similar to:  https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/15901/how-to-make-a-100-cotton-shirt-repel-moisture/15922#15922 https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/14226/rain-jacket-losing-waterproof-ability https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/22558/upgrade-jackets-to-be-water-and-wind-proof/22559#22559

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upgrade jackets to be water- and wind- proof](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/22558/upgrade-jackets-to-be-water-and-wind-proof)

Answer (score 1):

3M makes a spray for this purpose "Scotchgard".  It's been around for decades.  You'll need to re-apply it every year or so for the water resistance to persist, and especially after laundering.  Beware, once your clothes repel water, they will also repel sweat, which may leave your skin wet beneath.